# How to create merge conflict between up-to-date - but differing - branches?

Tags: git, git-merge

I want to restore old piece of code into the current code.

Old piece of code is at an old commit that is a far parent of the current commit. Therefore there is no merge conflicts between these commits, merge results in "Already up-to-date.".

I would like to:

- use merge conflict view for the difference between commits and use conflict resolution to track what contemporary changes  I want to keep and what old code I want to restore.
- if possible - preserve git commit history: recent commits for unrelated code and old commit history for this old snippet I want to restore.

With `git checkout [--merge]` I succeeded only in getting either the old or the new version of a given file.

What is best way to achieve this or similar? Should I use tools outside of git?

EDIT: Merge conflict results in a sort of diff view in the worktree. This is easy to edit. How to recreate this? Best, if after the process, the resulting commit has as parents both commits of interest, therefore allowing git to trace the changes back in history.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You create a merge conflict by trying to merge two branches which have conflicting changes.

Comment: Why are you not happy that you can merge the two branches without conflict?

Comment: Are you looking for `git checkout -p`?

Comment: This whole question is based on a misconception. What you need is not a "merge conflict" view, it's just a `diff` view. And that is something that Git will give you directly, or you can host it in any number of terrific GUIs that will allow you to make the desired changes in the existing state of the file.

Comment: "old commit history for this old snippet I want to restore" That's another misconception. "snippets" (hunks we call them) don't have history.

Comment: It looks like you're looking for `git cherry-pick`.

Comment: Merge conflict view is indeed a diff view, yes. Conflicted merge applies such a diff view in the worktree. How to make it, what is the tool?

Comment: Code snippets may not have history, but there is a difference in copying code portions manually and creating a new commit with them OR merging these code portions from another commit. In the latter the code snippets have a searchable history of changes, call it as you wish.

Answer (score 2):

You want, as [mkrieger1 said in this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72044399/how-to-create-merge-conflict-between-up-to-date-but-differing-branches#comment127299490_72044399) or [jthill said in this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72044399/how-to-create-merge-conflict-between-up-to-date-but-differing-branches#comment127302892_72044399), either `git checkout -p` or `git cherry-pick`.  My guess is that the latter is likely to serve you better, but here is what you should understand about both operations:

- Git is all about *commits*, and each commit holds a *full snapshot of all of your files*.  (There's more to it than this but this is the key item here.)  These files are frozen for all time, and are otherwise like a tar or zip archive that you (or whoever) made of the source at the time you ran `git commit`.  They're *stored* in a special, compressed, read-only, Git-only, *de-duplicated* format, so they don't take extra space in spite of the fact that most snapshots mostly re-use most of the files from previous snapshots, but they're still full snapshots of all files.
- Git *shows* a commit by comparing the snapshot *in* that commit to the snapshot in its parent commit.  That is, suppose commit `b789abc` has parent `a1234546`.  (Each commit has a unique number, represented as a big ugly [hexadecimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal) hash ID; these are abbreviated hash IDs.)  There are two snapshots for these two commits.  Because the files *in* these snapshots are de-duplicated, Git can very quickly and easily discard, from the display, all the files that are 100% identical.  For the remaining (non-identical) files, Git compares them, as if playing a game of [Spot the Difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spot_the_difference), and shows you which *lines differ*.

This is why it looks like a commit holds a change, but in fact it doesn't.  (This is particularly important for *merge commits*, which have two parents but just one snapshot.  The commit-showing code has a problem here because there is no obvious parent to use to do a comparison, so by default, `git log -p` just doesn't bother showing *anything at all* about the merge.  The `git show` command by default does something clearly better, but arguably still wrong or misleading.)

The difference engine *in* Git is quite efficient and powerful, and can compare *any two commit snapshots*.  It can also handle a commit snapshot and a checked-out tree, for instance, and some other important cases, but let's just concentrate on the snapshots here.

This means you can run:

```
git diff <hash1> <hash2>
```

and Git will produce a diff—a change recipe—that, if applied to the snapshot from *`hash1`*, will produce the snapshot in *`hash2`*.  You can take this snapshot and edit it down to just a small set of changes and feed that to `git apply`, if you like.

But you don't have to do that.  The `git cherry-pick` command will take any given single-parent commit—it has trouble with merge commits for the obvious reason—and *compare it to its parent*, the way `git log -p` or `git show` does, to see what *changed*.  Then it will attempt to apply the *same change* to the *current commit*.  So you just check out what you want modified, then `git cherry-pick` the original commit that made that change, and now you have the same change made again.  The cherry-pick command even copies the original commit's log message (and author!) for you.  You can edit the message with `--edit` and reset the author with `--reset-author`.

If the change you want is mixed with other changes, and/or requires cherry-picking *many* commits, you can instead have Git run a diff of just the one file—the equivalent of:

```
git diff <hash> -- my/one/file.ext
```

—and then interactively let you pick each *change shown here* to the one selected file.  To get that, you just run:

```
git checkout -p my/one/file.ext
```

or:

```
git restore -p my/one/file.ext
```

(Both commands do the same thing here; `git restore` is just the new, less-error-prone way to do this.  The old `git checkout` command does too many jobs: it implements both `git switch` *and* `git restore`.  To avoid having just one device that both applies a band-aid *and* replaces your entire body, the Git folks finally split this up into two separate commands.)

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll need to craft merge commit and the file as separate actions.

To craft the commit, you can build the merge you wanted, keeping the newer file and then amend the commit with changes to the file.

To create the changes to the file, you can use `git diff` to look at how the file has changed over the commit range and then either patch the file or edit it manually.

If there's a lot of changes you want to pick through, you can have a new ref on the branch and then cherry pick off of the commits you don't want.

Comment: only looking at the diff view and patching manualy or using git checkout -p - both are tedious. I would prefer to recreate what conflicted merge does in my worktree.